# Finding closest combinations of a given sum without replacement

Tags: python, vba, combinations, mathematical-optimization, combinatorics

I have been dipping my feet into programming and originally was making a simple macro in VBA to find a certain combination that sum to a given number when given a list of inputs. I imagined a number of tasks and minutes to do those tasks, and inputted a number of people to divide the minutes approximately equal between them. To give a concrete example, if I had eight tasks and three people, I might have the following variables:

```
M = [44,39,29,77,102,35,40,59]
N = 3
Avg = sum(M)/N
```

I want the program to be able to find the set of combinations for each person that sum closest to the average value. For instance in this example, I would like an output of something like:

```
A = [102, 40], B = [44,39,59], C = [29,77,35]
```

If anyone can at least lead me in the right direction with regards to this project, I would be grateful. While this began as an aside from a macro for an Excel sheet, I wouldn't mind if I learned more about optimization algorithms in a more suitable language like Python.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the comment. I apologize for giving such an open-ended request, as I am rather new to programming for a non-structured project. I had never previously heard of the max-min fair allocation problem and did not know where generally I should learn this. If you can give me any additional resources so in the future I can make sure to go to them first and only use Stack Overflow for specific technical questions, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The "set of combinations for each person that sum closest to the average value" sounds incorrect because it seems like the sum would often be greater than the average task — so I assume you meant the average of the combination. Anyhow, this sounds like an optimization problem, and sometimes they can usually be solved via the "brute-force" technique that involves checking every possible combination (see the `itertools` module). These can sometimes be sped-up by stopping the evaluation of some possibilities early.

Comment: Thanks for being so patient with me; it really goes a long way. I understand now I should have done more leg work; as a rather new user, I was rather ignorant in knowing the next steps other than it required some optimization. Also, I think you are right that my wording is clunky, I should have stated a set of combinations that sum closest to the average.

Answer (score 1):

Getting each persons work as close as possible to the mean is equivalent to [max-min fair allocation problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egalitarian_item_allocation)

It’s essentially an optimization problem — google research did some work on this here

https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/45386.pdf

A CS professor wrote a Python module for this https://github.com/anirudhSK/cell-codel/blob/master/schism/utils/max-min-fairness.py